# Lazy Loading Implementation In HTML Table in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lazy-loading

I have one API which return thousands of records. When I am rendering that on screen, UI starts lagging. So I thought to implement it using lazy loading.

I want to load more data as user scroll and remove elements from UI and render new elements as user is scrolling means I just want to render that data on UI which is needed but I am not able to find any good resource for lazy loading table data.

I have created one code sandbox for that.
https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-nightingale-glvdp8

Can anyone please help with the same?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're two ways that we can use in this situation :

1- React-Window library : https://react-window.vercel.app/#/examples/list/fixed-size

2- Create lazy loading behaviour from scratch, but this will need some changes in the backend, as we will divide the data into pages and send a page ( which will contain n records ) at a time, you can see how to implement it here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZKUirTtxcg

Comment: Isn't the second option just pagination of the data?

Comment: Yes the same way of sending n articles to blog per page, but the difference we will make it like infinite scrolling (until we reach end of our data) , so it's like a small trick that will help

Comment: Hey @MohamedAshraf, 
Thanks for the answer. I think React-window can help.

Let me check it.

Comment: @MohamedAshraf, I am facing issue with react-window. Can you please check it once?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74169155/react-window-calling-renderrow-function-infinitely

Comment: Hey @Kelly, I added an answer it should help.

Comment: Thanks @MohamedAshraf, But I never thought that style tag can cause such issue.

Comment: Anytime, ya me too when I used it for the first time, but it seems to be the problem, if you can mark it as an accepted answer it will be great.