# React-Window Calling RenderRow function infinitely

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lazy-loading, react-window

I have used `react-window` to render large list on UI. Not sure why it's calling the RenderRow function infinitely when I scroll and it's not able to render the pending rows when I am scrolling (showing me blank screen).

Can anyone please tell me, what I am doing wrong?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a small thing that was missing, which is the style that must be send to `Row` so the code of the `RenderRow` will be :

```
const RenderRow = ({ index, style }) => {
    const item = combinedData[index];

    return item.isServiceParent ? (
      <div style={style} className="service-parent-name">
        <p>{item.title}</p>
      </div>
    ) : (
      <div style={style} className="service">
        <p>{item.name}</p>
      </div>
    );
  };
```

Comment: Hey Mohamed, 
Can you please help with one more thing?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74204264/react-sortable-or-jquery-ui-like-sortable-on-react-window-list

Comment: Hey Kelly, I have take a look at it, and you have to use `react-window-sortable` instead of `react-window` not with it, I saw an expamle but it was using class components https://github.com/ntbosscher/react-window-sortable/blob/HEAD/example-fixed-sized-list.tsx

Comment: I tried, but react-window-sortable is not working. Can you please share any code sandbox with me where it's working?

Comment: class component will also work. but can you please share any live example which is working

Comment: Apologizes for late, but I was and still very busy, if it didn't work yet you can add a post so people can help